# Fullcalendar get calendar event created when clicking in agendaDay view

Tags: javascript, events, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar 3.2.0. When I go to the agendaDay view and click on a time slot, a new event is created automatically with a 30-minute duration by default. How can I have access to this event from the dayClick callback, so I can change its duration?

I'm implementing a page where you have a form that defines the duration of the event. You put the number of hours the event is going to last in an input and then you click on the agendaView of the calendar to create the event. In the dayClick callback, I get the start of the event and add to it the duration that was put in the input, then I render the event in the calendar. The result is that I get my rendered event overlapped by the automatically created one, like this:

[image]

I have to click outside the calendar to make the event disappear. I would like to prevent the automatic creation of the event in the first place or be able to change its duration when it is created and make it permanent, so it doesn't disappear when I click outside of the main calendar frame.

Here's my code:

```
$('#calendario').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    navLinks: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    dayClick: function(day, evto, view) {
        var txtDuration = $('#duration');
        var hoursOrDays = $('#hoursOrDays');
        if (view.name === "agendaDay") {
            // Here, is it possible to get a reference to the automatically created event and change its end date,
            // instead of creating a new one and rendering it?
            createEvent('Available', day, calculateEndDate(day, parseInt(txtDuration.val()), hoursOrDays));
        }
    },
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true
});

function createEvent(text, start, end) {
    var calendario = $('#calendario');
    var evento = {
        title: text,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        durationEditable: false,
        resourceEditable: false
    };
    calendario.fullCalendar('renderEvent', evento);
}

function calculateEndDate(start, duration, hoursOrDays) {
    var unit = hoursOrDays === 'D' ? 'days' : 'hours';
    return start.clone().add(duration, unit);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: that's not how you change the duration of an existing event. Changing duration / start time can be done via dragging. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/ . Also normally adding events is done via the "select" callback, not "dayClick". That allows the user to actually drag the event to the correct duration that they want without having to type. See https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/demos/selectable.html

Comment: @ADyson I know I can drag or expand the event in the calendar to change its duration. However, it's a requirement to put the duration of the event beforehand in an input, and then use the calendar to select in which day the event will take place as well as selecting the hour it is going to start. The event will not be editable. I'll try to use the select callback to implement what I want, thanks!

Comment: why is that a requirement? Sounds like whoever wrote the requirements is trying to define the user experience without actually consulting on what is technically possible. If you explain there's a more user-friendly way to do it and demonstrate it, I'm sure you can get the requirement changed.

Comment: I will try to change the requirements to create the events using the calendar only. However, I still have the problem that the created event disappears when I click outside the calendar. How to make it permanent?

Comment: as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/ you can set the last parameter "stick" to true, to make the added event persist when the view is changed. Not sure why it would disappear when you click outside the calendar though, unless that in itself triggers some other event.